# regarding $\mathbb P(|X| + |Y| \ge \epsilon) \le \mathbb P(|X| \ge \epsilon/2) + \mathbb P(|Y| \ge \epsilon/2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

We have a popular inequality ($\epsilon > 0$)
$$\mathbb P(|X| + |Y| \ge \epsilon) \le \mathbb P(|X| \ge \epsilon/2) + \mathbb P(|Y| \ge \epsilon/2).$$

I understood this by drawing a graph $x + y \ge \epsilon, x \ge \epsilon/2, y \ge \epsilon/2$ and comparing which area is larger.

Instead of this (unusual) method, is there some way to understand the above inequality based on traditional **probability theory** (or set theory maybe)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$A=\{\omega: |X(\omega)|+|Y(\omega)|\geq\epsilon\},\ \  B=\{\omega: |X(\omega)|\geq\epsilon/2\},\ \  C=\{\omega: |Y(\omega)|\geq\epsilon/2\}.$$
We claim that $A\subset B\cup C$. Indeed, if $\omega\notin B\cup C$, then $|X(\omega)|<\epsilon/2$ and $|Y(\omega)|<\epsilon/2$, hence $|X(\omega)|+|Y(\omega)|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$, and thus $\omega\notin A$. Therefore, $A\subset B\cup C$, hence
$$\mathbb P(A)\leq \mathbb P(B\cup C)\leq \mathbb P(B)+\mathbb P(C).$$